# GXT 2.3.0 supports GWT 2.?

Tags: gxt

I see the jar file name for GXT 2.3.0 = gxt-2.3.0-gwt22.jar. Does this mean it's expecting GWT 2.2??  Seems kinda odd considering GXT 2.3.0 was released Oct. 2013 and GWT 2.2.0 was released  Feb. 2011 (3+ years prior).
I tried GWT 2.6.1 and get an error in the GXT jar (HtmlEditor.java Line 548: Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.google.gwt.dom.client.Element to com.google.gwt.user.client.Element) so I'll try GWT 2.5, then 2.4, etc...

PS
I know this is WAY old stuff. I just need a temporary "fix" to run on IE10 then I'm going to go strictly with GWT; no more GXT. Thanx, ~rfh

Comment: GWT 2.5.1 compiles clean!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GXT2.x works with GWT upto 2.5.1 version. While according to official documents GXT 3.X works with GWT 2.6.1, I myself tried GXT 3.X with GWT 2.7.0 and no problems till now.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not asking about sencha GXT. Sencha is working fine with my project. But, the problem I am facing with Ext-GWT.